# problema em converter matriz normal para numpy

Tags: python, numpy

O programa organiza é feito para organizar as linhas, com base no valor da terceira coluna, fiz o programa e deu certo, mas quando uso matriz numpy, da o erro abaixo. eu preciso usar matriz numpy porque faz parte de um programa maior que estou usando numpy.

```
import numpy as np

y = np.matrix([[-1,1,4],[2,-2,7],[10,7,1]])

c = True

def OrdenaMatriz(y):
    matriz = []
    matriz.append(y[0])
    for a in range(2):
        if y[a,2] < y[a+1,2]:
            matriz.insert(a,y[a+1])
        else:
            matriz.append(y[a+1])
    return matriz

while c == True:
    a = OrdenaMatriz(y)
    if a == y:
        c = False
        print(a)
    y = a
```

ERRO QUE ESTA DANDO:

```
DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an 
error in the future.
  if a == y:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 26, in <module>
    a = OrdenaMatriz(y)
  File "teste.py", line 19, in OrdenaMatriz
    if y[a,2] < y[a+1,2]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: Ola @João-Vitor-Degrandi, tudo bem. Posso tentar ajudar, mas o que seria uma matrix normal ? Seria uma lista de listas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que ocorre é que `y` é sempre uma matriz, já o output da função `OrdenaMatriz()` é uma lista de matrizes (vetores). Isto é:

```
>>> y = np.matrix([[-1,1,4],[2,-2,7],[10,7,1]])
>>> y
matrix([[-1,  1,  4],
        [ 2, -2,  7],
        [10,  7,  1]])

>>> a = OrdenaMatriz(y)
>>> a
[matrix([[ 2, -2,  7]]),
 matrix([[-1,  1,  4]]),
 matrix([[10,  7,  1]])]
```

Ao fim do primeiro loop vai acontecer `y=a`, Então agora `y` é uma lista de matrizes e não mais uma matriz.

Só que no segundo loop (já que ainda temos `c=True`) ele começa tendo aplicar `OrganizaMatriz(y)`, porém a função espera uma matriz como argumento e não uma lista de matrizes.

Então você tem que fazer o seguinte:

```
>>> a = OrdenaMatriz(y)
>>> while c == True:
...     if a == y:
...         c = False
...         print(a)
...     y = a
[matrix([[ 2, -2,  7]]), matrix([[-1,  1,  4]]), matrix([[10,  7,  1]])]
```

## NOTA [EDITADO]:

Acredio que o output da função OrdenaMAtrix(y) devesse ser uma matriz e não uma lista de matrizes. Assim, sugiro essa modificação:

```
def OrdenaMatriz(y):
    matriz = []
    matriz.append(y[0])
    for a in range(2):
        if y[a,2] < y[a+1,2]:
            matriz.insert(a,y[a+1])
        else:
            matriz.append(y[a+1])
    return np.asmatrix(np.asarray(matriz))
```

Assim você pode aplicar o seu loop original modificando apenas a condição de `if`:

```
c=True
>>> while c == True:
...     a = OrdenaMatriz(y)
...     if (a==y).all():
...         c = False
...         print(a)
...     y = a
...
[[ 2 -2  7]
 [-1  1  4]
 [10  7  1]]
```